# if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A and an eigenvalue of B is it also an eigenvalue of AB?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is essentially explained in the title: given that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ matrix A and another $n \times n$ matrix B, is also an eigenvalue of AB?

Comment: What's your definition of eigenvalue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; consider the matrices $A=B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$, or more generally $A=B=\lambda I$ with $\lambda\neq0,1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $-I$, $(-I)^2=I$ ( we suppose $-I=A=B$) and -1 is an eigenvalue of -I but not of $I$